# How should the low frequency schematic of this amplifier look like?

Tags: circuit-analysis

[image][image]

I know the model for a transistor at low frequency (first pic), but I never thought of a more complex schematic like this one. It also specifies that Cc is very high, that means it's not going to be a short anymore?

Comment: Of course, it would be possible to create a low-frequency model for the shown circuit - however, why on earth do you want to do this? For which reason? I will not simplify the analysis of the circuit. Most of the time you will spend to find the small-signal low-frequency schematic.

Comment: "low frequency" might be interpreted here relative to f_T / beta , rather than C_C * R_L

Answer (score 1):

Don't confuse the linearized model (the first one) with an actual application schematic (the other one).

The linearized model is for *one* BJT, and aids in studying what happens under some conditions. The other schematic is actually an application build with *three* BJTs (each one can be modeled by the first schematic). In fact it's a simple amplifier with a current mirror to load the collector (it has some properties that make it better than a collector resistor).

As for Cc I don't get what you mean. Cc AC couples the output signal and with Rl forms an high pass filter, was that you wanted to know?

Comment: Thanks a lot! Our teacher taught us that at low frequency the capacitors become a straight line in the circuit, so now I do not know why does it specifies that it's very high

Comment: no, capacitors have reactance (look in the textbook)and that goes down with frequency. Intuitively it's an open circuit at DC and a short circuit at high frequency. The inductor is exactly the opposite. These fact are used also in analysing the bias (DC) point of the circuit